# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable shows but no show in other file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# for loop
input = int(input('input a number:'))
num1 = 0
num2 = 0

for x in range(1, input + 1):
    num1 = 0 + x
    for y in range(1, input + 1):
        num2 = 0 + y
        print(num1, '*', num2, '=', num1 * num2)

# while loop
input2 = int(input('input a number:'))
num3 = 1
num4 = 1

while num3 <= input2:
    while num4 <= input2:
        print(num3, '*', num4, '=', num3 * num4)
        num4 = num4 + 1
    num3 = num3 + 1
    num4 = 1
```

After executing, for loop running well, but while loop show a error msg:

```
input2=int(input('input a number:'))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

However, if I copy/paste while loop into another file and execute it,
there's no error message and code executes properly.

Could anyone tell me what's the problem?
Thank you so much.

Comment: **Do not** use `input` as a variable name.

Comment: ...especially if you plan on calling it later, which is the reason for your error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
input=int(input('input a number:'))
```

this reassigns the built-in function `input` to the number the user picks. Then when you call it later...

```
input2=int(input('input a number:'))
```

it still thinks `input` is a number (thus "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable").

This is bad for all the same reasons you don't call your throwaway list `list`. Take care not to shadow built-in names.

Comment: i got it. Thanks so much!!